# Is $a_{0} + a_{1}y_{1} + a_{2}y_{2} + ... + a_{n}y_{n}$ a linear combination of vectors $y_{1},..., y_{n}$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I understand that the following is a linear combination of vectors $y_{1},..., y_{n}$:

$a_{1}y_{1} + a_{2}y_{2} + ... + a_{n}y_{n}$

My doubt is whether, the following which has an additional constant term $a_{0}$, can also be called a linear combination of vectors $y_{1},..., y_{n}$:

$a_{0} + a_{1}y_{1} + a_{2}y_{2} + ... + a_{n}y_{n}$

Comment: I assume your $a_i$s are scalars and your $y_j$s are vectors. What does it even mean to add a scalar to a vector?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it isn't. In fact, it doesn't make any sense, since $1$ -appearing in the first term as $a_0\cdot 1$, is not supposed to be a vector of your vector space, in general.

For instance, assume your vector space is $\mathbb{R}^2$: can you add $1$ to $(5,-3)$?

Comment: For some reason when combined with the OP's nickname and acceptance of the answer, I remembered my psychology while I was writing my thesis. :)